# Robotium : Testing the app integration with third party apps

Tags: facebook, ui-automation, robotium, android-testing, sikuli

I want to know, if there's any way to test multiple apps in android? I'm aware btw that you cannot launch / test another app from the app under test with Robotium.

Basically, I'd like to automate the test cases involving FB login in my app. So how are such test cases automated in other companies? Almost every other app has integration with FB, so how are those test cases tested?

In short : My native app launches the FB's login activity. After logging in the control goes back to my app. I want to automate this login scenario. Robotium doesn't allow me to do that. At present the solo.getCurrentActivity() doesn't even detect that FB activity is open.

Some basic searches revealed that you could do that in Sikuli, but it works only on non-rooted devices. I'm interested in running my test on real devices, and real devices can't always be rooted.

Any thoughts on how to go about it?

Thanks,
Abhijeet

Comment: There is a wealth of information on testing mobile devices with the Selenium framework.  Have you explored that at all?

Comment: Are you referring to Android Driver? If so, isn't it used for testing mobile web app? I'm sorry if my description was confusing. I'm trying to automate the android app.

Comment: You can use WebDriver to login to Facebook's Login Webview. It won't work for Facebook's native app though. You need to root your phone & resign the Facebook app with your app's keystore for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @dannyroa, this helps. I was referring to both native app login and the webview facebook login scenarios. I don't want to use rooted devices for my testing because I then my testcase would fail just because a device isn't rooted.   BTW, I haven't tried this but I believe there are methods in Robotium that would allow you to automate the webview also.